# What do the # and & symbol signify in mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, integral, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

I'm struggling to make sense of the following output of an integral in mathematica:

Root[c#1^4 + a #1 + b & 1]

What exactly does this mean? I've looked up the documentation for # and & but putting everything together to understand the above expression is a tad confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: Thats a "Pure Function":  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html

Answer (score 1):

Thing of the # and & as a way of injecting values into a function call, that's how I tend to read it.

For example

```
Map[Print[#]&,{1,2,3}]
```

would inject the values from the list on the right into the Print[] call on the left.

Formally, look at the definition of the [Slot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)[] function which really helps.